# C++ Using an inline class in another inline class

Tags: c++, class, visual-c++, inline

I have two inline classes named Player.h and Game.h. I simply want to use the game class in my player class.

This is what i have tried in my player class, but it gives an unknown override specifier error when building:

```
private:
   Game game;
```

Comment: Please provide [mcve] of code (it's not clear what do you mean by "inline classes") and full error message, copied and pasted.

Comment: By inline i mean the option to specify the class as inline when adding it in visual studio so that you dont need a cpp file for the class and it all can be done in the header file.

Comment: Sorry if im being confusing im pretty new here.

Comment: Alright, I think I know what you mean. Still, a full error message and some code would be useful.

Comment: Error C3646 'game': unknown override specifier 
Error C4430 missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int 
Error C2065 'game': undeclared identifier 
Error C2065 'game': undeclared identifier 
Error C2065 'game': undeclared identifier

Comment: These are the errors i get when i try to build.

Comment: Do you possibly have Player.h include Game.h but also Game.h include Player.h? Just a guess. It would really help to update your question with the full contents of these header files (at the very least the basics of the class declarations, the relevant member variables, and the include statements). Otherwise any attempted answers are guesswork.

Comment: That was the problem. I was stupid not to think about that.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that i was including Player.h in Game.h and also Game.h in Player.h.